# What is the difference between double byte font and single byte font?

Tags: fonts, double-byte

I came across the term 'double byte' font when I was reading a technical documentation for a product. Googling the answer did not help either.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://www.allbusiness.com/glossaries/double-byte-font/4956020-1.html):

> **double-byte font**
>
> a font that uses two bytes (16 bits) to represent each character,
>   thereby allowing more than the 256 characters that could fit into a
>   single-byte font. Contrast ASCII , ANSI , and EBCDIC , which are
>   single-byte character sets.
>
> **single-byte font**
>
> a font that represents each character with a single byte, as in ASCII
>   , ANSI , or EBCDIC , and is therefore limited to 256 or fewer
>   characters. Contrast double-byte font ; Unicode .